# Model not converging towards distribution

Tags: python, keras, probability, distribution

I'm still a beginner to keras and playing around with it.
My current goal is to make a model learn a distribution. For this I have chosen the numpy beta distribution function. 
My aim was to make the model learn the beta distribution and tell if a value would be inside it or not.

So I made a csv with 5000 values of beta/rect values, which the model should learn from.

But when the model is learning there is absolutely no change in it. It seems I have a wrong approach to my problem or it can't be solved this way.

I've tried changing the model, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
data_size = 5000

X = np.zeros((data_size, 2))
Y = np.zeros((data_size, 1))

for i in range(np.size(X, 0)):
    X[i][0] = np.random.beta(2, 2)
    X[i][1] = np.random.random()
    Y = X[i][0]

np.savetxt('\values.csv', X, delimiter=',')
dataset = np.loadtxt('\values.csv', delimiter=',')
X_train = dataset[:, 0:2]
Y_train = dataset[:, 1]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to a GAN. 
The discriminator takes a distribution as inpu while the generator learns to reproduce it.

Works like a miracle and needs just a few epochs to converge.